# Ingresar datos de matriz en datos float java

Tags: java, matriz

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual tengo que crear una matriz bidimensional en java cuyos datos van a ser ingresados con datos tipo float. El código que hice para la matriz con datos int es:

```java
package Facturacion;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class matriz1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        float[][] matriz;
        int n,m,i,j;
        System.out.print(" ");
        n=input.nextInt();
        m=4;
        
        matriz=new float[n][m];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                System.out.print("MATRIX ["+i+"]["+j+"]=  ");
                matriz[i][j]=input.nextFloat();
            }
        }
               
    }
    
}
```

El problema que tengo, es que cuando ingreso los datos de tipo float para crear la matriz, el código se me rompe y no se como arreglarlo. Lo que si puedo hacer es que el resultado del print de la matriz muestre los datos en float, pero para este caso no me fue de utilidad.

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at 
java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939) at 
java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594) at 
java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496) at matriz1.main(matriz1.java:24)
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el error que te muestra?

Comment: Disculpa, no habia adjuntado el error, esto me sale: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)   
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)      
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496) 
        at reto1.main(reto1.java:24)

Answer (score 0):

A ver si te sirve como ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //declaramos matriz bimensional
    float[][] matriz;
    //declaramos las variables de enteros a utilizar
    int n,m,i,j;
    //pedimos las filas
    System.out.print("Ponga número de filas: ");
    //metemos las filas enla variable n
    n = input.nextInt();
    //pedimos las columnas
    System.out.print("Ponga número de columnas: ");
    //metemos las columnas en m
    m = input.nextInt();

    //damos las dimensiones de n y m a la matriz
    matriz = new float[n][m];
    //en el primer bucle lo limitamos hasta las filas de la matriz
    for (i=0; i < matriz.length; i++){
        //el segundo bucle lo limitamos al valor de las columnas de la matriz
        for (j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++){
           //vamos pidiendo los valores de la siguiente manera:
           //datos de los valores de la primera fila (0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)
           //datos de los valores de la segunda fila (1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)
           //datos de los valores de la tercera fila (2,0)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)
           //siempre en función del número de filas y columnas
           System.out.println("Escribe el elemento:[" + i + ", " + j + "] de la matriz: ");
           //recogemos los valores introducimos por teclado como float
           matriz[i][j] = input.nextFloat();  
        }
    }
    //imprimimos la frase
    System.out.println("Elementos de la Matriz: ");
    //para separar las filas ponemos una línea de iguales o cualquier otra cosa
    System.out.println("======================");
    //hacemos un bucle para las filas
    for(int ii = 0; ii < matriz.length; ii++){
        //hacemos un bucle para las columnas
        for(int jj = 0; jj < matriz[ii].length; jj++){
            //imprimimos la tabla de las columnas
            System.out.print(" | " + matriz[ii][jj]+ " | ");   
        }
        //separamos la nueva fila por la línea de iguales
        System.out.println("\n======================");  
    } 
}
```

Tu código lo veo bien, así que supongo que el error que te saldrá será por el símbolo que utilices para introducir los decimales que varía en función de lo que tengas configurado en el sistema.

En mi caso (11.0) me da error. (11,0) me funciona sin problemas

Comment: Claro, justamente ese es el error que tengo, que cuando ingreso los datos con (.) me sale el error, y es algo que tengo que mejorar porque los datos ingresados me llegan los decimales asi, por ejemplo 1.0 2.0 etc

Answer (score 0):

Este Ejemplo te puede servir

```
import java.util.*;

public class Bidimensional2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int FILAS = 5, COLUMNAS = 4;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j, mayor, menor;
        int filaMayor, filaMenor, colMayor, colMenor;

        int[][] A = new int[FILAS][COLUMNAS]; //Se crea una matriz de 5 filas y 4 columnas

        //Se introducen por teclado los valores de la matriz
        System.out.println("Lectura de elementos de la matriz: ");
        for (i = 0; i < FILAS; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++) {
                System.out.print("A[" + i + "][" + j + "]= ");
                A[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        //Mostrar por pantalla los valores que contiene la matriz
        System.out.println("valores introducidos:");
        for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) { 
            for (j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(A[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //Calcular el mayor valor de la matriz y el menor.
        //Obtener las posiciones que ocupan el mayor y el menor dentro de la matriz 
        mayor = menor = A[0][0]; //se toma el primer elemento de la matriz como mayor y menor
        filaMayor = filaMenor = colMayor = colMenor = 0;

        //mediante dos bucles for anidados recorremos la matriz
        //buscamos el mayor, el menor y sus posiciones
        for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {  //para cada fila de la matriz
            for (j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) { //para cada columna de la matriz
                if (A[i][j] > mayor) {
                    mayor = A[i][j];
                    filaMayor = i;
                    colMayor = j;
                } else if (A[i][j] < menor) {
                    menor = A[i][j];
                    filaMenor = i;
                    colMenor = j;
                }
            }           
        }

        //Mostrar por pantalla el mayor elemento de la matriz,el menor y las posiciones que ocupan           
        System.out.print("Elemento mayor: " + mayor);
        System.out.println(" Fila: "+ filaMayor + " Columna: " + colMayor);
        System.out.print("Elemento menor: " + menor);
        System.out.println(" Fila: "+ filaMenor + " Columna: " + colMenor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda, tengo el mismo error con tu ejemplo, es decir, cuando ingreso el float 1.0 por ejemplo se rompe el codigo:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at javaexample.Matriz2.main(Matriz2.java:19)

Comment: declaralo como double la matriz o si no agregale al valor que viene en decimal  la f para indicarle que es un float Example  **2.5f**

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar, me di cuenta que en el scanner puedo hacer uso de un metodo llamado useLocale, con lo cual el codigo me quedo asi:

package Facturacion;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class matriz1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
    double[][] matriz;
    int n,m,i,j;
    System.out.print(" ");
    n=input.nextInt();
    m=4;
    
    matriz=new double[n][m];
     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            System.out.print("MATRIX ["+i+"]["+j+"]=  ");
            matriz[i][j]=input.nextFloat();
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

}

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.